# Windows search bar is acting up in an abnormal way

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

Essentially, what happens is whenever I press the start button/use the windows key or go into the windows search bar, I get this full-screened loading screen for what I think the full-screened version of the search bar? Not sure; I mainly say this because it renders the search bar as completely nonfunctional while also not even appearing and, while I can't access it because that screen renders everything unable to be accessed, the start menu still pops up. To be more concrete with my description of the screen, essentially it blurs everything out behind it to a significant degree with a gray tint in front of it and has that blue dot loading sign seen across most modern Windows applications. By the way, the loading screen never loads; it usually just quits.

[image]

However, it is easy to exit out. All I need to do is press the windows key once for the start bar and twice for the search bar; still, having both functions be rendered as unusable is a major problem. I also have no idea of this initially occurred; it just kind of happened to me. I have tried using `WIN + Q` and other solutions but they seem to get me nowhere.

Comment: Make a new, test, Windows User Account. Test Search in the new Account. If that works, then the current Windows User Account is damaged.

Comment: Do you have `DisableSearchBoxSuggestions` enabled or disabled?, Start Menu behaving strangely while `DisableSearchBoxSuggestions`  is enabled is a common theme recently. There was also a recent Windows Update that addressed some issues with the Start Menu.

Comment: @Ramhound Just tried this. It's fixed now. Thanks!